# The system cannot find the path specified. node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998

Tags: node.js, tailwind-css, vite, react-tsx

I'm new to web development and nodejs stuffs.

I tried to create a react typescript app with vite & tailwindcss install.
But I got this error when I run

`npm create vite@latest`

cd to project

`npm install`

`npm run dev`

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Au Personal Folder\vite\bin\vite.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)        
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Thanks for every answers :)

Comment: I try create-react-app from another tutorial and still get the exact same error somehow :(